# How can git and svn use an existing ssh proxy?

Tags: git, ssh-tunneling, subversion, socks5-proxy

Due to some apparent fiddling on a hotspot I am using I cannot use https directly (the hotspot provider seems to have fiddled with it n some way) so I have set up an http proxy for use with Firefox.

I also notice that when I try to download a repo using `git` or `svn` doesn't work as well.

Is there a way to configure git and svn to connect through the existing SSH proxy automatically? I am thinking about additional options passed on the `git` or `svn` command invocation rather than through some changes in the configuration files

Comment: I would never use an hotspot that disables https. I considered putting up one to see if anyone would actually be dumb enough to connect to it and stream all his traffic through my equipment unencrypted

Comment: `ssh` is not a proxy.  The closest it can be used as is a tunnel, which matches a category you selected.  Therefore, the programs can not themselves control how they get tunneled since it is transparent to them.  This needs to be defined in routing or NATing rules.  So if you want help in defining those, you'll need to add very clear details on the network layout you're dealing with including routing and NAT tables from both sides of the tunnel.

Comment: Since you have the possibility of using SSH, you would probably have simpler solutions with VPNs.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Firefox is using it as a SOCKS5 proxy in the Advanced > Network settings, and that is why I call it proxy.

Comment: @JuliePelletier The hotspot appears to interfere with the VPN as well, which is why I switched to the SSH tunnel

Comment: It probably doesn't do protocol analysis and simply block certain ports so changing the port could work.